# Handlebars and html in template help - looping and displaying content in rows

Tags: html, handlebars.js

I'm having an issue with getting articles to dynamically render in html when I have rows with left and right cells. Below is my code. When I do this, the first article (article 0 in the index) is taking both left and right places in row 1. If I have 8 articles, I want 4 rows, each with two different articles, but instead I'm getting 8 rows of the same article left and right.

[image]

```
<!--=================-Rows with 2 items in each section=================-->
<table width="640" align="center" class="em_main_table em_fixed" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        {{#each sections}}
        {{#ifEqual this.sectionId "section2-articles"}}
        {{#if this.items.[0]}}
        {{#each items}}
        {{#ifEqual this.contentType "article"}}
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center"  class="em_pad">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <table width="276" class="em_wrapper" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" >
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" class="em_top_5" >
                                    <a href="{{url}}" target="_blank" class="em_text_none" >
                                        <img src="{{imageUrl}}?W=276" width="276" height="175"  class="em_img3" border="0" alt=""/>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="5" class="em_height em_f_h_zero">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" class="em_black1 em_heada" >
                                    <a href="{{url}}" target="_blank">{{title}}</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>   
                        </table>
                        <table width="276" class="em_wrapper" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" >
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top"  class="em_top em_top_5" >
                                    <a href="{{url}}" target="_blank" class="em_text_none" >
                                        <img src="{{imageUrl}}?W=276" width="276" height="175"  class="em_img3" border="0" alt=""/>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="5" class="em_height em_f_h_zero">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" class="em_black1 em_heada" ><a href="{{url}}" target="_blank">{{title}}</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="30"  class="em_height em_f_h_zero">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
         {{/ifEqual}}              
         {{/each}}
         {{/if}}
         {{/ifEqual}}
         {{/each}} 
</table>
<!--=================-Rows with 2 items in each section=================-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Indent your code, is the only way you can read it properly.
Use `div`s and css clases to do this job not tables.